# Formatting Textbox (Userform VBA in Excel 2010) to Dutch mobile phone number

Tags: vba, excel-2010, userform

Fellow StackOverFlow-ians,

I come to you with another question that i'm trying to learn from.
I have a UserForm which adds Employees to an Employee-database.
Code is as below, and working perfectly.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim iRow As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("Employee-Data")

iRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row

ws.Cells(iRow, 4).Value = Me.TextBox1.Value
ws.Cells(iRow, 3).Value = Me.TextBox2.Value
ws.Cells(iRow, 7).Value = Me.TextBox3.Value
ws.Cells(iRow, 6).Value = Me.TextBox4.Value
ws.Cells(iRow, 15).Value = Me.TextBox5.Value
ws.Cells(iRow, 9).Value = Me.TextBox6.Value
ThisWorkbook.Save
Unload Employee
End Sub
```

My problem is as following, I want to restrict the format of TextBox6 to a Dutch telephone-number, which is 06-########. I want TextBox6 to show 06- and make it only able to type 8 numbers in as Value.

I've tried the following and more:

```
Private Sub TextBox6_Change()
TextBox1.Text = Format(ws.Cells(iRow, 9).Value,"##""-"########")

End Sub
```

What is my error in thinking here, am i using a wrong approach? Can anybody suggest a decent solution for this problem? As said before, trying to learn from my errors, so please tell me what I'm doing wrong instead of just providing a solution.

Comment: Isn't textbox6 being assigned the value in Cells(iRow, 9)? Format column 9 as "text" and entire the data there as you want it to appear in textbox6.

Comment: Maybe I didn't make myself clear enough. I want the preset text "06-" shown in the Userform TextBox6. So when they enter the "06-"11111111 (only the remaining numbers), the value returns to my sheet as 06-11111111. Do you think this is possible?

Comment: Oh sure. Add "06-" & before Me.Textbox6.Value. So it reads `ws.Cells(iRow, 9).Value = "06-" & Me.TextBox6.Value` You may need to format the cells to text or something because it might give you a date otherwise. Answer is below :)

Comment: Just to explain, everything between the " " is what text you want and the & is the command to add the rest of your instruction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ws.Cells(iRow, 9).Value = "06-" & Me.TextBox6.Value
```

Be aware of cell formatting as you may get a date. Convert to text or number etc.

Comment: Would i do this in a Private Sub?

Comment: In your code, yes. Just add that small portion `"06-" &` in front of `Me.TextBox6.Value`

Comment: You won't see it in the text box but it will show in the cell when its done.

Comment: Ahhhhh, now i get it. How do i go upon showing something like this in a TextBox. Because my users, are you know, users. I want them to see and enter the remaining 8 numbers. If I do it like this my users will probably end up with the value of 06-06-11111111..

Comment: You could simply add a label in front of the textbox. and on the label properties, change "caption" to 06-. That way, they will see the 06- in front of the textbox and won't enter it. You could also just put a label stating don't add the code, just enter your 8 digit number or something.